# MOSFET bootstrap switching circuit switching OFF problem

Tags: mosfet-driver, nmos

Currently I am designing a power switching circuit. The goal is to switch on a N channel MOSFET with a low side load. The circuit should work with input Voltages up to around 60 Volts. The switch is controlled by an Arduino Uno. The problem that I have is the OFF switching seems not to work properly in real life.

I have built the circuit on a bread board and I simulated it as well in LT Spice. Below is a figure of the simulation in LT spice I used existing LT spice models for some parts. In real life for the OpAmps I use "OPA454AIDDA". As N FET I use "IXFH60N50P3". For the P  channel I use "FQP4P40".

The switching code is as simple as 2ms ON pulse (switchON) followed by a 18ms (switchOFF). So this should result in a 50 Hz output with a 10 percent Duty Cycle. This is done with an Arduino Uno.

Working principle of the circuit:

During the ON time, the upper Op Amp powers the gate of the N FET resulting in a positive Vgs, turning the load on. When the load is powered, the bootstrap capacitor boosts the gate Voltage to further activate the NMOS.

The lower OP Amp circuit works as a substractor circuit. During the ON time, the OFF signal is LOW. This should result in a 0 Vgs of the PMOS. When the OFF signal goes high, the Vg should result in Vs-Voff. This gives a negative Vgs, enabling the PMOS. Which should now switch off the NMOS because it will have a Vgs of 0V.

In the simulation the circuit does work as hoped. As is shown in the output signal in the figure. But in real life, the switching OFF does not work properly. Below 30 Volts input it works fine, but as soon as I increase the Voltage to higher levels with my Lab bench power supply, the output pulses are not a stable pulse but are rapidly switching on and OFF during the ON time. My question is how can I improve the circuit to get cleaner output pulses when my input Voltage increases. Also, what other improvements do you guys think I could make?

Thank you in advance!

PS this is my first time posting on the forum so I hope you guys have enough information on the question. Feel free to ask.

[image: LT Spice simulation Circuit]

[image: LT Spice simulation output]

Comment: That circuit is overly complex to just turn on a load. Why use opamps at all?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with the P-channel MOSFET.  Have you looked at its actual Vgs during the simulation?  If you click the probe on the G node, hold it down, drag to the S node, then release the click, it will plot the voltage difference between the two.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The simulation works fine the problem I have is after I built the same thing in real life. It works fine for a Voltage range of V1 up to 35 V or so. Plotting the Vgs in LTSpice I have done before that works as expected.

I would like this circuit to create high fast rising and falling current pulses (I will lower the load's ohmic value to increase the current). This will generate high and fast changing currents. This is to generate magnetic fields used for testing measuring equipment's immunity to interference. I am doing this for a research purpose.

Comment: I use the N channel because it has low Rds ON which is important for me. The P channel MOSFET is used for switching the N channel OFF. It will effectively set the Vgs of the NMOS to 0. The control of this PMOS gets tricky at higher voltages. Its OFF when Vgs is 0 it is ON when the Vg is more negative than the Vs. At Voltages of 60V on the source, you need around 45-55 V on the gate to turn it ON. When going lower say you would apply 0 to the gate. you will likely destroy the PMOS because it can not handle Vgs of -60V. I tried alternatives but did not succeed.

Comment: Without the PMOS: when the NMOS gate is low, the NMOS's switches OFF much slower (if it switches OFF at all). The NMOS's gate still holds some charge due to its parasitic capacitance so it will stay on for some time until the capacitor is discharged.

Comment: @WillyBogard, OK.  Reason I asked is because I duplicated your simulation and the Vgs on the IRF9640 never goes negative.

Comment: Here is my schematic and plots so you can see.  I get the same output on the load as you but the Vgs on the P-channel doesn't do what you say you want it to do. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjptl.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn7ti.png

Comment: Oh you are kind of right! The Vgs does not go negative when the OFF goes high. It only goes negative when both signals for ON and OFF are high simultaneously. This is not desirable. I made the following change: The non inverting input of the lower Opamp I connected to the output of the upper Opamp instead of connecting to the Vcc. 

Now I also need to add a charge pump to the Vee of the lower OpAmp to get a negative Voltage. 
https://imgur.com/GGKSZTV

Thanks for the comment!